# Clustering binary data : feature selection vs Apriori

Tags: clustering, feature-selection, unsupervised-learning, association-rules, apriori

My data set is a 999 rows x 964 columns `Panda DataFrame`.

Each row is a user. 
My data is binary : 0 for absent and 1 for present.

I would like to fit the users into X clusters. The unsupervised algorithm should give me the clusters by the end of the Analysis.

I don't know if I should be using feature selection first, then Clustering, or using the apriori method to get the frequent pattern.
And second, I want to classify my data into clusters. Which best unsupervised algorithm is preferred in this case ?

Comment: No such rule, try and see what works.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to cluster, the column or the rows. Still, a t-sne of the thingy is giving you some insight?